Cross compiling for ARM: Floating point exception when using fixed size array declarations
When cross-compiling a C program for the Raspberry Pi, the resulting executable fails with a Floating Point Exception when executed on the Pi. I could narrow it down to this minimal C program which reproduces the issue:
int main() {
    char x[1];
    return 0;
}

The size (1) does not matter either, same problem with 1024 or any size of the array.
The error does not occur if I

remove the char x[1] line
replace it with x = malloc(1)
move the declaration to global space (would imply some issue with stack vs. heap??)

Cross compiling is done with this docker image:
FROM ubuntu:24.04
ENV BUILD_DIR="/build"
ENV CPATH="/usr/local/include"
WORKDIR /root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        cmake \
        git \
        build-essential \
        gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf \
        gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi \
        g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf \
        g++-arm-linux-gnueabi 

RUN git clone https://github.com/hannenz/pigpio && \
    cd pigpio && \
    make CROSS_PREFIX=arm-linux-gnueabi- && \
    make install

WORKDIR ${BUILD_DIR}

docker run -it \
    -v /home/hannenz/pidev/projects/pi/kiddyblaster:/build \
    -w /build \
    -e BUILD_DIR=/build/build \
    -e SRC_DIRS=/build/src \
    pidev \
    arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o test test.c

scp test raspberry-pi:/home/pi/

and execute it on the Raspberry Pi:
pi@kiddyblaster:~ $ ./test
Floating point exception
pi@kiddyblaster:~ $ echo $?
136

The Raspberry Pi is Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1 with a fresh installed PiOS Lite (Raspian 12):
pi@kiddyblaster:~ $ cat /proc/cpuinfo | tail -n 14
processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a01041
Serial          : 000000006a731e3b
Model           : Raspberry Pi 2 Model B Rev 1.1
pi@kiddyblaster:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm

I'd be glad for any hint on where I can start to debug this. Is it something with the cross compile toolchain? Memory management? Little/Big Endian? something ARM-specific? The stack / heap?

Sounds like a compiler bug.

Make it to emit some assembly. Or use objdump to get it from the ELF. It's a small reproducing code, should be not that hard to analyze what is going on (unless the issue is in crt0.o or something...I would suspect that it is compiled for some incompatible architecture variant.

This very much sounds like your compilers are confused about which one is called and which linker is doing the linking. I've not used Ubuntu, and for PiOS supporting Pis I generally just build on the Pi itself, but for Pico do use gcc-arm-none-eabi for building on Linux and running on the Pico. There setting the proper build environment so only the cross-compiler tools are used during the build is critical. It sounds like either you are compiling with the cross-compiler and linking against your local runtime or vice-versa. Double check.

See: ARM Thumb function where you can create a Linux executable with any tool chain and no 'C' support code.  The issue is not your code, but the tooling.  The 'C' startup is triggering this exception.  Did you try to attach a debugger?  Can you get a call trace?  It will indicate which 'C' startup is responsible.

I found out what caused the issue: I need to use the gnueabihf variant of the tools (compiler, linker etc., e.g. arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc), i think the "hf" stands for "hard float" and refers to the missing FPU on the raspberry pi?
I moved to using the docker images from this repo: https://github.com/tttapa/docker-arm-cross-toolchain and everything works fine. Thanks for your comments and replies
